# ActionBarSherlock not import

Tags: android, dependencies, actionbarsherlock, library-project

I have a problem with actionbarsherlock that it drives me crazy!

I have a new workspace, I imported my project and the library projects. There is also actionbarsherlock library project.

My project doesn't generate R file, I suppose because there isn't actionbarsherlock in library path.

```
image 1
```

[image: Red error is the actionbarsherlock lib]

I import the library project and fix the path...

```
image 2
```

[image: fix path of actionbarsherlock]

I clean project but if I return to project properties in the android section I SHOW LIKE **IMAGE 1**!!!!! It seems like eclipse doesn't save project's changes..

I try:

- Change `project Build Target to 4.2.2` (In my project and in actionbarsherlock).
- Change in java compiler the `1.6 java compiler compliance level` (checked "enable project specific settings").
- Change in **manifest.xml** `android:minSdkVersion="8"`.
- Add android support libraries.
- Refresh & clean projects...

  **What am I doing wrong?????**

I post 2 other images and the eclipse problems..

```
image 3: my project
```

[image: my project]

```
image 4: actionbarsherlock project: I change android 4.3 to 4.2.2 after screen capture..
```

[image: actionbarsherlock project]

**Eclipse problems**

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Sherlock'.
Cannot cast from Activity to MainActivity.
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid'.
Menu cannot be resolved to a type.
```

etc etc...

Thak you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have only one problem. ie, ABS library import. If it is fixed, second problem will vanish.

The problem is your library location(you fade out it in pics;)). Try this,

> 1.Delete the library from project explorer(be careful, don't delete original files from disc).
>
> 2.Go to your original workspace folder and make sure that the library ABS(actionbar sherlock) is out of all other folders( the folder
>   contains only that library). If not, cut&past it out( or you can paste
>   it inside your project folder).
>
> 3.Import the library from new location.

Now, add the library to your project and see if the problem resolved.

Comment: try it but nothing. Thank you for your answer. I think that delete the new workspace to make another would be better..

Comment: Ok. go ahead. Now, inside your workspace, only 2 folders- ABS&your project (1 library, 1 project). Did it solve?

Comment: no, I use the hardest way, but it works. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

After some time, to fix them I did some things:

- Delete all my project in eclipse (not from disk).
- Close eclipse.
- New Workspace (3rd).
- change directory of actionbarsherlock and my project
- import in eclipse all actionbarlibrary (with sample project, actionbarsherlock-i18n, etc..).
- import my project
- fix library
- close another time eclipse
- now it seems to work...

Thanks to all for your answers.